# VirtualTreeView Finalize in C++ Builder for UnicodeString

Tags: c++, delphi, memory-leaks, c++builder, virtualtreeview

I use a VirtualTreeView in C++ Builder and use it with structure like this:

```
struct TVTNodeData
   {
   int Index;
   UnicodeString Caption;
   }
```

I pre-fill nodes of the tree using loop that has this:

```
TVirtualNode *Node = VTree->AddChild(NULL);
pNode = (TVTNodeData *)VTree->GetNodeData(Node);
pNode->Index = 1;
pNode->Caption = "Whatever";
```

I noticed that the memory for the application is constantly increasing (memory leak) even though I clear tree and reload it. This page - http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2010/06/09/memory-leaks-when-using-virtual-treeview-component/ recommends to do Finalize() in `OnFreeNode` event. Good so far.

But there is no Finalize() in C++. I tried `pNode->Caption=""` in `OnFreeNode` event and memory no longer is allocated that drastically but it still is a bit. I think there might be reference to UnicodeString left even though it is emptied (reference count > 0).

How do I free node data in `OnFreeNode` event for UnicodeString in C++? I know that UnicodeString is allocated until all reference count is zero - so how do I force reference count to become zero?

Also, what if node is allocated in `OnNodeInit` - does the same applies in `OnFreeNode` event?

What if TVTNodeData structure is purely virtual - the node is never visible nor initialized neither using AddChild nor OnNodeInit, is then Finalize required, does the structure even exists in memory then?

**Update:** I discovered later that I was measuring memory usage incorrectly and that for strings setting them to empty string is really enough for clearing memory data. But - as Rob Kennedy suggests in his answer below, calling struct ~destructor is even better and equivalent to Finalize and also easier as it clears entire structure (if you have more strings in it).

Comment: Have you specified the correct `NodeDataSize`? also try validating each node that you add to the Tree, also is `WideString` an option for the Caption?.

Comment: Yes, I did ``VTree->NodeDataSize = sizeof(TVTNodeData);`` before the loop. WideString is possible but what is the advantage of using it? It is not reference counted so setting it to empty string deallocates all memory? Isn't UnicodeString more VCL-friendly?

Comment: WideString is COM BSTR type and is managed by Windows COM heap allocator, with no reference counting. but simply setting UnicodeString to empty string should be equal to Finalize.

Comment: Thanks, I found that there is no leak after all. But I did found that WideString consumed less memory than UnicodeString can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes, `WideString` consumes less memory than `UnicodeString`. `Widestring` contains only a 4-byte integer (the string length) in addition to the character data, whereas `UnicodeString` contains two 4-byte integers (the string length and the reference count) and two 2-byte integers (the element size of each character - always 2 - and the string codepage - always `CP_UTF16`) in addition to the character data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delphi's `Finalize` has the effect of freeing any compiler-managed types in a record. In C++, that's typically the job of a type's *destructor*. In your `OnFreeNode` event handler, call your data type's destructor directly:

```
TVTNodeData* const pNode = static_cast<TVTNodeData*>(Sender->GetNodeData(Node));
pNode->~TVTNodeData();
```

That will call the destructor of the `UnicodeString` object, which will free the associated character data. When the tree control allocates the `TVTNodeData` for a node, it's in the same block of memory as the `TVirtualNode` object itself, so you can't just call `delete`.

The tree control initializes the data with all-bits-zero. If you have an object in your data for which that's not the correct initialization (which, to be formally correct, includes *all* non-POD types), then you should call the *constructor* of your data in the `OnInitNode` event. Use *placement new* to do that. For example:

```
TVTNodeData* const pNode = static_cast<TVTNodeData*>(Sender->GetNodeData(Node));
new (pNode) TVTNodeData();
```

That will call the constructors of the `TVTNodeData` members without allocating memory for an additional `TVTNodeData` instance.

If a node is never initialized, then it won't be finalized, either. The `OnInitNode` event will have never run, so the tree will know that the node hasn't been initialized. Uninitialized nodes don't get finalized, so you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks, as I also figured out I could call ~TVTNodeData() but I was worried that might produce some Access Violation later (which it didn't at first). I also now understand better mechanics of VirtualTreeView. Thanks for this answer, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think not all of your nodes were validated, perhaps because they weren't shown. Try calling ValidateNode after AddChild.

Comment: So you are saying Finalize is not required in C++ programs and setting UnicodeString to empty string cleans all of its used memory?

Comment: After some more tests I found that ValidateNode doesn't make any difference. There seems to be no memory leak. If node is not initialized no memory is consumed. I did find though that WideString consumed less memory than UnicodeString (given the fact the listview had thousands of entries - thousands of WideStrings/Unicodestrings), can someone confirm is this true that WideString consumes less memory?